# Influxdb sending corrupted data as axios response

Tags: axios, influxdb

My axios request:

```
return await axios({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Token ${process.env.INFLUXDB_API_TOKEN}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.flux',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
  },
  timeout: 60000,
  data: query,
});
```

Coming response data:

```
♀t{�L�~~�?��↨_♀K�→��OW_}0xO�¶mo
�@zC�'§�↓�▼�⌂���q||�����۟▼����⌂~�����▼���?�}��~�������▼o?޿����▼����׿∟o���#,�/�~������4�����o▲��↓��▼}����↑y��������_����▼�}�������������o�
������<d+�~↔�i���♂9�c�→9♂�]�p5r����:����A�[���5W�����V�u�S�∟��9�u��F�B�k�j����k▬kX������5,����-ְ etc.
```

Query I send:

```
 from(bucket: "plc-metrics")
  |> range(start: 1693256400, stop: 1693310660)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "PLC_Sim8e786f156e5d1f06-total_count")
  |> sort(columns: ["_time"], desc: true)
  |> limit(n: 2000)
  |> group()
```

Result I got when I use same query in influxdb dashboard query script:

```
,result,table,_start,_stop,_time,_value,_field,_measurement
,,0,2023-08-28T21:00:00Z,2023-08-29T12:04:20Z,2023-08-29T12:04:17.808Z,64,val,PLC_Sim8e786f156e5d1f06-total_count
,,0,2023-08-28T21:00:00Z,2023-08-29T12:04:20Z,2023-08-29T12:04:07.805Z,63,val,PLC_Sim8e786f156e5d1f06-total_count
,,0,2023-08-28T21:00:00Z,2023-08-29T12:04:20Z,2023-08-29T12:03:57.804Z,62,val,PLC_Sim8e786f156e5d1f06-total_count
,,0,2023-08-28T21:00:00Z,2023-08-29T12:04:20Z,2023-08-29T12:03:47.803Z,61,val,PLC_Sim8e786f156e5d1f06-total_count
,,0,2023-08-28T21:00:00Z,2023-08-29T12:04:20Z,2023-08-29T12:03:37.792Z,60,val,PLC_Sim8e786f156e5d1f06-total_count
,,0,2023-08-28T21:00:00Z,2023-08-29T12:04:20Z,2023-08-29T12:03:27.792Z,59,val,PLC_Sim8e786f156e5d1f06-total_count
```

So data is successfully inserted influxdb, I can see it from influxdb dashboard table. But I got corrupted data when I try to get data with axios. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed after updating axios version from 1.2.0 to 1.2.1